# How to open pdf file in Nautilus as new Okular tab?

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, nautilus, pdf, okular

This works in the previous version (tested on 16.04): set Okular as default pdf viewer. Open nautilus, double click pdf file. Open another pdf file will bring new tab to Okular. But this method didn't work in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I already configured Okular to "Open new files in tabs" by checking it in Okular's General Options.

Note: It works, opened as a new tab, if I drag the pdf file from Nautilus to the opened Okular. It also works when I open pdf file via Okular > File > Open (or open recent). But it doesn't work when I double click pdf file in Nautilus, nor via right-click > open with other applications > Okular.

Is there any workaround?

## Update

This behaviour in my case is related to the dual monitors issue. That is, if I opened Nautilus not in main monitor, it will open new Okular instead of new tab. But if opened other pdfs from Nautilus which is located in the main monitor, it will be opened as a new tab in already opened Okular. Even if I moved Nautilus to the auxiliary monitor after it, the clicked pdf is still opened in a new Tab. The requirement is that, first, I **must** located Nautilus in main monitor when opening pdf via Okular.

So, this is my current workaround: locating nautilus in the main monitor first when opening pdf via Okular.

Comment: You may try adding the `--instance` option to the `.desktop` launcher of Okular. That option probably will ensure that the PDF is opened in the existing instance, but I am not sure if that is how this option works.

Comment: Can you make it more specific? I tried to edit org.kde.okular.desktop under /usr/share/applications. I added `--instance` in Exec line; hence it becomes `Okukar --instance %U`. But nothing changed. Okular still opened a new app instead of a new tab.

Comment: It is Nautilus fault. Caja from MATE desktop works normally without any additional file editing. It is time to drop buggy Nautilus or whole GNOMEs Hell.

Comment: Looks good what you did. A I also tested (with flatpak install, though), and it did not work. @N0rbert do you confirm you can get this to work with Caja (or Thunar, or any other file manager)? They all use the same xdg standards to associate file extensions.

Comment: Caja works as expected even on 21.04.

Comment: I added information that in my case the issue is related to dual monitors.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to dual monitor use with Okular. N
To enable open pdf file as new tab, here are the steps:

1. Open Nautilus in **main** monitor
2. Click/open any pdf file from that nautilus
3. Move nautilus to second monitor
4. Open another pdf files.

Now, the new pdf files will be opened from Okular's new tab instead of New Window.