# Okular not opening PDFs in tabs in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, pdf, okular, tabs

Been using Okular as my PDF reader for a long time as I like many of its features. Recently I switched from Xubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 and now I cannot make Okular to open the PDFs in new tabs instead of windows. Here my settings:

[image]

I have only one screen so I ruled out [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1343606/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-nautilus-as-new-okular-tab).

Comment: seems to be a bug

https://github.com/flathub/org.kde.okular/issues/36

I might be tempted to do an alias to overwrite Okular, taking the filename as a function parameter, opening Okular, or testing then switching if open, xdotool alt-f keys (whatever ) to open the menu, and copy and paste the filename ... a lot of bother ..  see link, manually doing a file open from Okular does not have this problem. running from terminal okular --noraise <filename> did open a new window.

Comment: I tried to find the config file, and only found the two rcc files that only relate to gui menus. not snap.